# Check the iOS status bar hidden with a modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, statusbar

so i'm using the "Utility Application" template in Xcode and have the **Main View Controller**, where the user can hide and show the status bar using a button. I've also got the **Flipside View Controller**, using a modal segue, which has a done button to return to the **Main VC**. I've set it up so that whenever viewing the **Flipside VC**, the status bar is always NOT hidden. This means that if the user hides the status bar on the **Main VC** and transitions to the **Flipside VC**, it will animate on and if the user didn't hide the status bar and they transition, nothing happens to the status bar.

That's all good, the problem is transitioning back from the **Flipside VC** to **Main VC**. I need a condition to check the hidden state of the status bar in the **Main VC**, which would be called in the **Flipside VC** when pressing the done button.

I've looked into using a BOOL as well as NSNotificationCenter to send a message to the **Flipside VC** about the state of the status bar.

I had this code:

```
-(BOOL)checkStatusBarHidden:(id)input
{
    BOOL result;

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES)
    {
        result = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        result = NO;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But this is all just guessing and thinking I might be able to use it somewhere to inform the **Flipside VC** of the status bar state. I thought of maybe changing the

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES)
```

to something like

```
self.statusBarHidden = YES //which of course isn't going to work
```

But anyway, as I said it's guessing and i'm not sure what to do.

Comment: for the God sake why do you need an `if` statement there?. Couldn't you just write `return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden`? **EDIT** It's even wrong since your are assigning instead of comparing, due to the use of `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yup, I dunno I suppose I could, sorry but i'm not very experienced with programming that's why i'm asking here, but that was just some extra info, not really part of the question :/

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yea, i'm assigning :( sorry, wasn't asking about how correct the syntax was though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774968/under-ios-7-how-do-i-hide-and-show-status-bar-on-the-fly-whenever-i-want-to/19867698#19867698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think of storing the information about the status bar state in the `MainViewController` using a property, e.g.

#### In your `MainViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL statusBarHidden;
```

then you can access that value from the `FlipsideViewController` using the `presentingViewController` property.

#### In your `FlipsideViewController.h`

```
MainViewController * mainVC = self.presentingViewController;
if (mainVC.statusBarHidden) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

As a final remark, **please** change your `checkStatusBarHidden:` method to something like

```
- (BOOL)checkStatusBarHidden {
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden;
}
```

Comment: OK that seems good thanks a lot. One thing though, if I put:

    MainViewController * mainVC = self.presentingViewController;
    if (mainVC.statusBarHidden) {
       // Do stuff
    }

in the FlipsideViewcontroller, I get the error **Unknown type name...MainViewcontroller** I'm guessing because I didn't import the **Main VC.h file**, but I can't or don't even need that do I?

Comment: Yes of course you need to add `#import "MainViewController.h` into your `FlipsideViewController`